# 2 DWT Tridion 2013 questions

Tags: 2013, templating, dwt

Not sure if I can post my questions here, please tell me where to move my question if necessary...

1) I added to a page a custom metadata schema. In that schema, there is an embedded component field 'Summary'.

The components that I can add in that metadata field all have a Title and Article field.

How can I show in the page template with DWT the contents of the Article field?

`@@Summary@@`  -> displays only the tcm-id of the embedded component

`@@GetFieldValue("MetaData.Summary", 0)@@`  -> displays only the tcm-id of the embedded component

`@@Summary.Component.Field.Article@@` -> displays nothing

I tried many other forms, but none of those works. Anyone got an idea?

2) When I loop the components to display the contents in my page template, I also want to access Target Group information and display for example a  around the content, if that target group is checked by the editor while placing the component on the page. With what syntax I can do that ?

Kind regards, hope somebody will point me in the right direction!

Herman

Answer (score 4):

DWT is not that powerfull to read fields from linked components out of the box. You can check SDL AppStore to see i there is some templating (dwt) extensions that can read fields from linked components. If you want to read those fields without extension you can write c# code fragment (or .Net assembly) in order to read and push content to the package from linked components so you can use it later in dwt.

Comment: Aha! Yes, we have the DGX installed, but I am searching for the documentation. Can't seem to download it (link is broken)...

Answer (score 2):

You can read fields from linked components in DWT. You need to programmatically using C# fragment read component, push it into package and then use

```
@@Get("Summary.Fields.Article")@@
```

to read it.

Answer (score 1):

I managed with the DGX to find the solution:

```
@@Get("Summary.Fields.Article")@@
```

Now the second problem of the target groups is still hanging...